# Can't install snap in RHEL 7.6 or 8.1

Tags: rhel

I have tried both OS using Azure VM

Is always a similar error related to SELinux. I have no experience with RHEL but the client is asking for it and I can’t install the tools I need without snap. Any idea how to force this install or download an rpm and install it directly?

The error I'm now getting on 7.6

```
Processing Dependency: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2 for package: snapd-selinux-2.54.1-1.el7.noarch
---> Package squashfuse-libs.x86_64 0:0.1.102-1.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: snapd-selinux-2.54.1-1.el7.noarch (epel)
           Requires: selinux-policy-base >= 3.13.1-268.el7_9.2
           Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch (@rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.15
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7_0.10.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.10
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7_0.11.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.11
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7_0.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.12
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.12.1-153.el7_0.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.13
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.8.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.8
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.13
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.17.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.17
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.18.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.18
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-23.el7_1.21.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.21
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-60.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-60.el7_2.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.3
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-60.el7_2.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.9
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.4
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.13
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.15.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.15
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.16
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.el7_4.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.4
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.el7_4.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.5
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.el7_4.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.9
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7_6.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.5
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.6
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7_6.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.9
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7_6.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.12
           Available: selinux-policy-minimum-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.15
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.12.1-153.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.12.1-153.el7_0.10.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.10
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.12.1-153.el7_0.11.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.11
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.12.1-153.el7_0.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.12
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.12.1-153.el7_0.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.13
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.8.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.8
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.13
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.17.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.17
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.18.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.18
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-23.el7_1.21.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.21
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-60.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-60.el7_2.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.3
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-60.el7_2.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.9
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7_3.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.4
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7_3.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7_3.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.13
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7_3.15.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.15
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.16
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.el7_4.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.4
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.el7_4.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.5
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.el7_4.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.9
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7_6.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.5
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.6
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7_6.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.9
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7_6.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.12
           Available: selinux-policy-mls-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.15
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-153.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-153.el7_0.10.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.10
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-153.el7_0.11.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.11
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-153.el7_0.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.12
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.12.1-153.el7_0.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.12.1-153.el7_0.13
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.8.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.8
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.13
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.17.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.17
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.18.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.18
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-23.el7_1.21.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-23.el7_1.21
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.3
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-60.el7_2.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-60.el7_2.9
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.4
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.13.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.13
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.15.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.15
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-102.el7_3.16.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-102.el7_3.16
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.4
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.5
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-166.el7_4.9
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.3.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.3
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.4.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.4
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-192.el7_5.6
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.5.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.5
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.6.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.6
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.9.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.9
           Available: selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.12.noarch (rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-eus-rpms)
               selinux-policy-base = 3.13.1-229.el7_6.12
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing `snapd-selinux-2.54.1-1.el7.noarch` from EPEL pulls in the `snapd-selinux` package as well. `snapd-selinux` requires the *latest* SELinux base policy ("base" is synonymous to `selinux-policy-targeted`).

The latest SELinux policy is package `selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-268.el7_9.2.noarch`, however you seem to have `selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-229.el7_6.15.noarch` installed.

So, if you upgrade from 7.6 to 7.9 you should be good.

Alternatively, you could turn to old versions of `snapd` and `snapd-selinux` on https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/epel/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I started a new VM 7.9 and the package seems to be there now but there is no snapd. This message I get now                                                        
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

No package snapd available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Did you enable the EPEL repo?

Comment: When I run sudo yum install epel-release , I get: Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

Nothing to do. Does this mean I need a subscription with RedHat?

Comment: Same message when I run : sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-*-optional-rpms \
>                            --enable rhel-*-extras-rpms \
>                            --enable rhel-ha-for-rhel-*-server-rpms
This system has no repositories available through subscriptions.

Comment: Please try `wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm; sudo yum install epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm`.

Comment: Ended up requesting to use CentOS instead of RHEL. Looks like the issue is because I don't have a subscription with RedHat I can't install snap. No issues with CentOS. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: OK. Consider accepting or upvoting the answer if it helped you.